# How to change weight of priorities in Kubernetes Scheduler?

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler

I want to increase the performance of the Kubernetes scheduler by changing the weight of the priorities (or eliminate some priorities), I want to know how I can change the weight of the priorities in the scheduler? and what is a default scoring strategy used by kubernetes?

Comment: Learn details about default scheduling policies for scoring in - [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/kube-scheduler/#scoring)

Comment: You can also configure `kube scheduler` using - 

`kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration `
For more info visit [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/scheduler-perf-tuning/#percentage-of-nodes-to-score)

Comment: But I want to know if kubernetes scheduler use all scheduling policies for scoring nodes or it based on one policy?, and how I can configure weight of priorities using kind: KubeSchedulerConfiguration ?

Answer (score 2):

I think this file has defined the default policies: [github source](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/scheduler/algorithmprovider/defaults/defaults.go). You can modify the default policies and weights by passing a policy-config file ([example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.5/examples/scheduler-policy-config.json)) with `--policy-config-file` option to kube-scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes 1.14 introduced stable prioritization of the nodes (Priority is enabled by default in Kubernetes 1.14+).

To give priority you have to create [Priority Class](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/#priorityclass) and later use it in YAML. A PriorityClass object can have any 32-bit integer value smaller than or equal to 1 billion. Larger numbers are reserved for critical system Pods. Below example of creating PriorityClass

```
apiVersion: scheduling.k8s.io/v1
kind: PriorityClass
metadata:
  name: high-priority
value: 1000000
globalDefault: false
description: "This priority class should be used for XYZ service pods only."
```

Later you have to include `priorityClassName` in your YAML under `spec` section like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  priorityClassName: high-priority
```

For more detailed informatio, please check [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I think there's a misunderstanding. I want to know if kubernetes scheduler use all scheduling policies for scoring nodes or it based on one only?, and how I can configure weight of priorities to change strategy of scheduling ?

Comment: You asked how to change weight of priorities in Kubernetes. Kubernetes scheduling pods based on `Priority Class`, from the highest one to lowerest one. 
If you mean, how kube-scheduler selecting proper node, it depends. As per documentation `For every newly created pods or other unscheduled pods, kube-scheduler selects a optimal node for them to run on. However, every container in pods has different requirements for resources and every pod also has different requirements. Therefore, existing nodes need to be filtered according to the specific scheduling requirements.`

Comment: Scheduling strategy is to create pods from highest priority to the lowest. Maybe you mean how kube-scheduler filtering nodes in order to know where create pod? This information can be found here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling/#kube-scheduler-implementation